# How to find the width of tables or cells?

Tags: html, html-table, stylesheet

How do I find the width of a table or columns in a table without specifying it in HTML or Javascript?

For example:

```
<table id="myTable">
<tr><td>column a</td><td>column b</td></tr>
</table>
```

In Javascript:

```
var tbl = document.getElementByID("myTable");
alert(tbl.style.width);  //will be undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct correspondense between CSS style keywords and javascript keywords. In your case, you need tbl.offsetWidth, not tbl.style.width. See [this quirksmode article](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/getstyles.html) for starters.

Answer (score 0):

It's dangerous to attempt these things in raw DOM calls because browsers differ.

The safe thing is to use a library (like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)) and use their routines.

To do exactly your example in jQuery:

```
 $("#myTable").width()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
var tbl = document.getElementByID("myTable");
alert(tbl.clientWidth);
```

It work's fine in FireFox, but you should check it in IE.